# cmake installation

Tags: software-installation, cmake

I am trying to install cmake on ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

everything starts fine, but downloading of package gets stuck

`Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 cmake-data all 3.16.3-1ubuntu1 [1,612 kB] 95% [1 cmake-data 1,509 kB/1,612 kB 94%`

I tried different servers as main, US, Slovak but without any change

Any clues on how to solve this?

The system is installed in VMware, win 7 as host

Changing mirror, cleaning cache, fresh installation of ubuntu 20.04 did not help.

Installing any other package works

Comment: Goes smoothly here on the NL server.

Comment: Tried NL server, same problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your package download have been corrupted. In such cases do

```
sudo apt clean && sudo apt update
```

Then repeat your installation command again. Changing to other mirror also could help in some cases.

You could also try to download it:

```
$ sudo apt download cmake-data
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 cmake-data all 3.16.3-1ubuntu1 [1 612 kB]
Fetched 1 612 kB in 11s (150 kB/s) 

$ ls | grep cmake
cmake-data_3.16.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb

$ sudo apt install ./cmake-data_3.16.3-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

You could also try to download it directly using `wget`:

```
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cmake/cmake-data_3.16.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Also, try to use different network configuration settings: use bridge instead of NAT and vice versa. If your host PC is connected through wi-fi, try to use a different wi-fi hot spot, as it also could be the cause of apt errors.

Installing `cmake` using Ubuntu Software is also could be used as an alternative way.

Comment: Didn't help, even fresh installation of ubuntu in VMware

Comment: Finally I installed cmake via Ubuntu Software, seems work fine. Anyway download cmake-data still not working

Comment: Ok, I'll include this option to the answer, so you could accept it if you want